# System.Diagnostics.Process locks the files when Process.UseShellExecute=false used

Tags: c#, process

I have found a lock file issue with `System.Diagnostics.Process` when it is running several threads from the console application.

For example, I run two command-line applications (`App1`, `App2`) using the code below and pass two different files for each app (`App1 -> File1`, `App2 -> File2`)

Sometimes, the `App1 -> File1` finish processing the file, but for an unknown reason, File1 is locked by the `App2` app.
It is not possible to read the File1 file until `App2` exits, through File1 was executed with App1 app in the first `System.Diagnostics.Process` instance.

This problem only happens when `Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute` is set to `False`. I need to disable shell execute to be able to read Process.StandardError property if execution fails.

Any idea what is going on? Is the code below thread-safe?

```
    using (var p = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = "c:\commandLine.exe",
            Arguments = "c:\file.jpg",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        }
    })
    {
        try
        {
            p.Start();
            p.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.Normal;

            p.WaitForExit();

            var output = await p.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
            var error = await p.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();
            var exitCode = p.ExitCode;
            return .....; 

        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (!p.HasExited)
                    p.Kill();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                //The process is not found, probably executable was not fount                    
            }

            p.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you redirect standard input as well?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError What do you mean redirect standard input?

Comment: You know [RedirectStandardInput = true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_RedirectStandardInput).

Comment: It deals with stream input and I don't use it. I pass all options using Process.StartInfo.Arguments. How this property could be related to the problem?

Comment: I vaguely recall a similar issue I was having where enabling this fixed it, but I don't remember all the details.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I will try tomorrow and let you know. Thanks for trying to help, spend three days without any idea how to fix that.